# What are the obstacles to the Modi Government implementing "One Nation One Election"?

Tags: election, india, prime-minister

Prime minister of Republic of India Narendra Modi has emphasized on multiple occasions for the need of ["One Nation One Election" Programme](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/one-nation-one-election-need-of-india-says-pm-modi/article33183867.ece).

In India some kind of election is always happening in some part of country, which costs lot of money. It becomes quite a blocker to the nation's progress. Opposing parties with opposite ideologies and mindsets sit in different parts of the government.  Opposing views are fine, but sometimes such conflicts become hurdles in nation building projects.

With the majority they have in parliament:

1. Is it easy for the Modi Government to bring about this change?
2. If successfully implemented what are the likely downsides of "One Nation One Election"?

Comment: The Hindu does a pretty good job of summarising this https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/one-nation-one-election/article28073916.ece

Answer (score 4):

There would probably need to be some constitutional adjustments.  These need a special majority to pass (50% of members and 2/3 of those present in both houses). Moreover depending on exactly how it was done, it could affect the the representation of the States, or the manner of the election of the President and Parliament.  Such changes require ratification by the State Legislatures. These additional requirements would make it difficult for Modi to achieve this without cross-party support (as intended)

Constitutional changes would be needed as the current Constitution doesn't define an election schedule for Parliament and the states that ensures that they remain aligned. It may be possible to tinker with the timings of the elections only using normal laws, but a Constitutional act would be more certain to achieve the result that Modi wants and prevent future change.

The benefits and costs are a matter of opinion, but lower costs is a benefit, while the mixing of national and local issues is a perceived disadvantage: When local elections occur at the same time as national ones, people tend to vote in the local elections on national issues.  *The Hindu* has [an article explaining the merits and demerits of such a system.](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/one-nation-one-election/article28073916.ece)